# Why is "Lemma 9.6" the default and not "9.6 Lemma"?

Tags: numbering, amsthm

As a reader, I never really understood why is it so common for textbooks to have the numbering à la `Lemma 9.6`. To me it seems to imply that we also have `Lemma 9.5` and `Lemma 9.7` but sure enough, `9.5` is a definition and `9.7` is an example. So when I started writing my first big assignment, one the first things I googled was how to `\swapnumbers`.

But unlike the creators of TeX packages and most users of the TeX.SE, I know little to nothing about typesetting. So I assume that the default option wasn't chosen randomly and would be happy to know the reason and maybe become convinced that `Lemma 9.6` is the way to go.

Update: just to clarify, I meant why

`Definition 9.5`

`Lemma 9.6`

`Example 9.7`

as opposed to

`9.5 Definition`

`9.6 Lemma`

`9.7 Example`

So I'm not questioning the unified numbering (which it a good thing beyond any doubt).

Comment: For that you can use `ntheorem`.

Comment: Because if you refer to it, it's weird to say *As we derived in 9.6 Lemma*. And if you are searching for a lemma 9.6, it's a royal pain in the ass, if every kind is numbered on its own. Then definition 9.9 comes after lemma 9.3 and you have to check every page to catch it. But I share your bitterness, I think this stuff is archaic and we need to get a better way of it. I am not quite sure what.

Comment: It mostly depends on what you are thinking to be numbering: if you're numbering paragraphs (*à la française*), then the number goes first; if you're numbering the statements, then the number goes second.

Comment: I guess 'off topic', but in English 'Lemma 9.6' makes sense whereas '9.6 Lemma' doesn't as a 'name'. Note that it's the same for something where the numbers do run through: 'Section 1', 'Section 2', _etc._ and not '1 Section'.

Comment: I also think it is to emphasize the difference between a section and a small unit such as a lemma, theorem etc.

Comment: @percusse: `cleveref` could handle this case intelligently, I think.